# android market - application update does not work

Tags: android, google-play

I have a new version of my app on the market and an old one installed on tablet. I expect to see download/install option when I navigate to the application page on the market but instead I see "open" button as if the market version were already installed on the device. `versionCode` is incremented in market's version.

What could be a reason for this?

Comment: Was the old version installed from the market as well?

Comment: no. installed it using adb. does it make a difference?

Comment: I think it does make a difference, as you probably didn't sign the adb one the same as the market one, although it may still be a problem if you did sign them the same. Try uninstalling and installing directly from market, it should be OK.

Comment: Sure this will make difference between application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of your app installed using adb is probably not signed, or if it is the signature doesn't match the one on the app in the market. First need to uninstall the version that was installed using adb then the market version should install without a problem.